# Invalid syntax on n2 keeps coming up

Tags: python, syntax

I have tried all with this code to try to understand why it keeps coming back with Invalid Syntax:

```
def ex27() :

    print("program will add 4 numbers and respond with an answer")
    n1 = int(input("Enter N1: ")
    n2 = int(input("Enter N2: ")
    n3 = int(input("Enter N3: ")
    n4 = int(input("Enter N4: ")
    n5 = n1 + n2 + n3 + n4
    print(n1, "+", n2, "+", n3, "+", n4, "=", n5)
```

`n2 = int(input("Enter N2: ")` - this is the line it comes up on, it says n2 is a Syntax error.

Comment: It's always the

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this:

```
def ex27() :

    print("program will add 4 numbers and respond with an answer")
    n1 = int(input("Enter N1: "))
    n2 = int(input("Enter N2: "))
    n3 = int(input("Enter N3: "))
    n4 = int(input("Enter N4: "))
    n5 = n1 + n2 + n3 + n4
    print(n1, "+", n2, "+", n3, "+", n4, "=", n5)
```

You missed the proper closing parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

You're not closing your parentheses.

Each line should look like:

```
n1 = int(input("Enter N1: "))
```

with two parentheses at the end of the line!